# Tangent portfolio weights without short sales?

Tags: optimization, finance, risk-assessment

Consider a mean-variance investor in a world with a risk-free asset.

Let $R_f>0$ be the return of the risk-free asset, $\mathbb{E}(R_i)>R_f$ the expected return of the risky asset $i$ and $SD(R_i)$ the standard deviation of the return of the risky asset $i$ for $i=1,...,N$.

Let $V$ be the variance-covariance matrix of the returns of all risky assets and $\bar{R}$ be their expectation.

Returns of risky assets can be positively correlated.

The weight of risky asset $i$ in the tangent portfolio is $x_i^\star=\frac{y_i}{\sum_{k=1}^N x_k}$ with $y_i=\{V^{-1}(\bar{R}-R_f)\}_{ii}$ if we allow for short sales. Hence, $x^\star_i$ can be **strictly positive** or **strictly negative** or **zero** (right?).

Question: which are the weights of risky assets in the tangent portfolio if we do not allow for short sales? Are they all **strictly** positive? If not, under which additional restrictions are they all **strictly** positive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To understand how to proceed you have to dispense with the formula and look at the derivation of the tangent portfolio from first principles. The multiobjective model is
$$\begin{array}{ll}
\text{maximize}   & (\bar{R}^T x + R_f x_f, - \tfrac{1}{2} x^T V x) \\
\text{subject to} & \vec{1}^T x + x_f = 1
\end{array}$$
The zero risk solution is of course $x_f=1$, and the maximum return solution is $x_i=1$ where $i=\textrm{argmax}_i \bar{R}_i$. To examine the rest of the tradeoff curve we
scalarize the model with $\gamma^{-1}\in(0,+\infty)$ as the weight of the risk term. (The reason we use the reciprocal will become clear later.) 
$$\begin{array}{ll}
\text{maximize}   & \bar{R}^T x + R_f x_f - \tfrac{1}{2} \gamma^{-1} x^T V x \\
\text{subject to} & \vec{1}^T x + x_f = 1
\end{array}$$
The Lagrangian is
$$L(x,x_f,\lambda) = -\bar{R}^T x - R_f x_f + \tfrac{1}{2} \gamma^{-1} x^T V x - \lambda ( \vec{1}^T x + x_f -1 )$$
The optimality conditions are
$$-\bar{R} + \gamma^{-1} V x - \lambda \vec{1} = 0 \quad - R_f - \lambda = 0 \quad \vec{1}^T x + x_f = 1$$
Eliminating $\lambda$ and solving for $x$ yields
$$x = \gamma V^{-1} ( \bar{R} - R_f \vec{1} ) \quad x_f = 1 - \vec{1}^T x.$$
The tangent portfolio is found by finding the value of $\gamma$ for which $x_f=0$: $$\gamma=\left(\vec{1}^TV^{-1}(\bar{R}-R_f\vec{1})\right)^{-1}.$$
This coincides with the solution you have offered in your post.

Now that the general principle is illuminated, we can apply it to the model with a short sale restriction. The zero risk and maximum return solutions are identical, so we immediately return to the scalarized model with a nonnegativity constraint added:
$$\begin{array}{ll}
\text{maximize}   & \bar{R}^T x + R_f x_f - \tfrac{1}{2} \gamma^{-1} x^T V x \\
\text{subject to} & \vec{1}^T x + x_f = 1 \\
                  & x \succeq 0
\end{array}$$
The Lagrangian is
$$L(x,x_f,\lambda,z) = -\bar{R}^T x - R_f x_f + \tfrac{1}{2} \gamma^{-1} x^T V x - \lambda ( \vec{1}^T x + x_f -1 ) - z^T x$$
where $z \geq 0$. The optimality conditions are
$$-\bar{R} + \gamma^{-1} V x - \lambda \vec{1} - z = 0 \quad - R_f - \lambda = 0 \quad \vec{1}^T x + x_f = 1 \quad z \geq 0$$
Eliminating $\lambda$ and $z$ yields
$$V x \geq \gamma(\bar{R} - R_f\vec{1}) \quad \quad \vec{1}^T x + x_f = 1$$
Unfortunately, even for fixed $\gamma>0$, it is not likely that there is an analytic solution for $x$ and $x_f$ (unless, say, $V$ is diagonal).

To determine the tangent portfolio, we need the value of $\gamma$ for which $x_f=0$. It also cannot be determined analytically, but it can be determined computationally.
\begin{array}{ll}
\text{maximize} & \gamma \\ 
\text{subject to} & V x \geq \gamma ( \bar{R} - R_f \vec{1} ) \\
                  & x \geq 0, ~ \gamma \geq 0 \\
                  & \vec{1}^T x = 1
\end{array}
The efficient frontier with a risk-free asset and a short sale restriction is no longer a straight line; I believe it is piecewise linear. So calling this a "tangent" portfolio may be a bit misleading. But it is still the portfolio found at the point where the tradeoff curves with and without the risk-free asset touch.

It is not necessarily the case that this new portfolio is strictly positive in all assets. I do not believe you can offer an a priori condition that ensures they will be.